# Eclipse Error External Editor

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, editor

all.

I am using Eclipse 3.8.1 on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. So, i am getting error when opening a file that i was set to external editor (Sublime Text) for editing.

Although I've done setting that external editor via **Preferences -> General -> Editors -> File Associations**, but i had to do resetting that when Eclipse restarted.

What is the solutions ? Thanks for the answer.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I use eclipse version 4.4.1 not from software center. 
I registered external editor(brackets) using Preferences -> General -> Editors -> File Associations - no resets, no restarts.

First i browsed to the wrong executable file, which didn't open brackets(which was the editor i was pointing). Then i corrected to shell script of the executable.

Then i tried the same opening external editor. Brackets opened successfully.

I think you have to check whether you pointed to the correct executable while adding external editor. Also i recommend using latest version of eclipse(Just extract and start using if openjdk already installed.)